# How to cite a document with multiple authors using natbib

Tags: latex, bibtex, citations

I would like to cite a paper by three authors so that all three of them appear in the text. I'm using natbib with the apalike bibliography style. According to natbib's documentation, the way to do this (and the way I remember doing it a few years ago) is to write `\citet*{bibliographykeyhere}`. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work now. Even declaring the package as `\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}` does not work, I get "X et al." instead of "X, Y, and Z" where the paper is cited for the first time.

For an example, this is one of the bibliography entries I want to cite:

```
@Article{ hoferszaboredeiszabo00,
 title = "{Reichenbach's Common Cause Principle: Recent Results and Open Questions}",
 author = "Gab{\'o}r Hofer-Szab{\'o} and Mikl{\'o}s R{\'e}dei and L{\'a}szl{\'o} E. Szab{\'o}",
 journal = "Reports on Philosophy",
 pages = "85--107",
 volume = "20",
 year = "2000"
}
```

When I use `\citet*{hoferszaboredeiszabo00}`, I get "Hofer-Szabó et al. (2000)"; I get the exact same output from "\citet".

I'd be very grateful for some pointers on what I should do.

Comment: Two questions:

(1) Did you recompile enough times to ensure that your changes to the `\citet*` are recognized? I often run into this problem with Sweave.

(2) Are you specifying `\bibliographystyle` as `plain` or `plainnat`?

Comment: Ad (1): Yes.
Ad (2): THANK YOU VERY MUCH, switching to plainnat solved my problem! But now the bibliography is in a format I don't really like too much; I'd prefer the "apalike" style. So, do I get this right and I simply should not use the "apalike" style together with natbib, if I want to use the "\citet*" command or the "longnamesfirst" option?

Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Using [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) rather than bibtex gives you much more freedom in how you cite multiple author papers, although you should ask yourself why do you need the full author list in the body of the text: it's unweildly and normally unnecessary...

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, I'll check out biblatex for future projects. A full author list is needed in some cases, where I am sure that all authors need to be credited -- that the reader should know without consulting the bibliography that an interesting result is not just by "X and friends", but by "X, Y and Z". This is especially appropriate in the case where you simply know from other sources that, of the three authors, it was the person Y who was mainly responsible for the particular quoted result.

Comment: As Seamus mentioned use the package `biblatex`, addtionally use the option `maxcitenames` with value greater or equal than the maximum number of authors you want to cite without "et al." at the declaration of the package. For example, `\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,maxcitenames=4,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,maxbibnames=10,sorting=nyt,natbib=true]{biblatex}`